# Microsoft Advertising won't load

Tags: firefox, internet, troubleshooting

Every time I try to visit http://advertising.microsoft.com/ in Firefox, I get this error.

[alt text http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/2009-08-26_212911.png](http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/2009-08-26_212911.png)

But when I use Internet Explorer or Google Chrome, everything loads just fine. Also does curl from command line, so I guess the problem is in Firefox itself. I'm currently using Firefox 3.5.2 on Windows Vista x64 SP2.

What could possible cause this?

Comment: Vista XP? Which OS is that? :P

Comment: @musicfreak: x64 .. stupid typo :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of add ons, if I was you, disable them all temporarily and restart and see if you can visit.

Also, sorry to sound stupid, but are you just pressing refresh on that error page or actually typing in and visiting http://advertising.microsoft.com

Comment: addon thingy worked, after disabling most of them it started working again :)

Answer (score 0):

Loads fine for me in XP with 3.5.2. Clear out your cache and try again.